# React not sending api requests for fetching data(axios get)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, axios

**ProductDetail page**

```
const ProductDetail = () => {
 const { id } = useParams();
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 const history = useNavigate();
 const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
 const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;
  useEffect(() => {
   console.log('fetching product')
   dispatch(listProductDetails(`${id}`));
 }, [dispatch,id]);


 return (
   <>
     {loading ? (
       <Loader />
     ) : error ? (
       <Message severity="error" error={error} />
     ) : (
       <div className="product-detail-wrapper">
        {product.name}
       </div>
     )}
   </>
 );
};
```

**productdetail action**

```
export const listProductDetails = (id)=>  async(dispatch)=>{
try{
    dispatch({type:PRODUCT_DETAIL_REQUEST})
    const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)         

  dispatch({
        type:PRODUCT_DETAIL_SUCCESS,
        payload:data.data.product
    })
    
}catch(error){
    dispatch({
        type:PRODUCT_DETAIL_FAIL,
        payload:error.response.data.message
    })

}
```

}

**product detail reducer**

```
export const productDetailReducer = (state={product:{reviews:[]}},action)=>{
switch(action.type){
    case PRODUCT_DETAIL_REQUEST:
        return {loading:true,...state}
    case PRODUCT_DETAIL_SUCCESS:
        return {loading:false,product:action.payload}
    case PRODUCT_DETAIL_FAIL:
        return {loading:false,error:action.payload}
    default:
        return state
}
```

}

**store.js**

```
import {applyMiddleware,combineReducers,createStore} from 'redux'
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import {persistStore,persistReducer,FLUSH,REHYDRATE,PAUSE,PERSIST,PURGE,REGISTER} from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import {modalReducer} from './reducers/productModalReducer.js'
import {addToCartReducer} from './reducers/cartReducer.js'
import { productDetailReducer,productListReducer } from "./reducers/productReducer";
import { authReducer } from './reducers/authReducer.js'
const reducer = combineReducers({
    auth:authReducer,
    productModal:modalReducer,
    cartAdd:addToCartReducer,  
    productList:productListReducer,
    productDetails:productDetailReducer,

})
const persistConfig = {
    key:'root',
    version:1,
    storage,
    whitelist:['auth'] //only added auth to persist

    
}
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig,reducer)
const initialState = {}
const middleware = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
const store = createStore(persistedReducer,initialState,middleware)
const persistor = persistStore(store)
export default store
export {persistor}
```

on hitting the product detail page
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

is there anything wrong with my code? The network tab is not showing API get requests for this particular page.. another API is working fine.

Comment: Looks like `productDetails.product` is undefined for some reason. Since both `productDetails.loading` and `productDetails.error` are initially falsey the UI code tries accessing `productDetails.product.name`. Are you using any sort of Redux state persistence where the `state.productDetails.product` is undefined? Was there some previous API call that failed and dispatched the `PRODUCT_DETAIL_FAIL` action where the reducer case strips out the `product` property? We need more details. Can you [edit] to provide debugging details? See [mcve].